# Plotting POSIXct timestamp series with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

I would like to plot the results of a load test.  Each row contains a timestamp in seconds and the response time for the request.  For example:

```
timestamp <- c(1441229131, 1441229132, 1441229133, 1441229134, 1441229135)
response.time <- c(22, 48, 48, 59, 52)
lt1 <- data.frame(timestamp, response.time)
lt1$datetime <- as.POSIXct(lt1$timestamp, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
```

However, when I try to plot this, the x axis shows wierd numbers instead od a properly formatted date.

```
g1 <- ggplot(lt1, aes(datetime, response.time))
g1 <- g1 + geom_point()
g1 <- g1 + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
g1
```

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to specify what you want on the x-axis using the library `scales` and the function `scale_x_datetime`:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(lt1, aes(datetime, response.time)) +
       geom_point() +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
       scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%M:%S"))
```

[image]

for more info, see `?scale_x_datetime`, `?date_format` and `?strptime`

Comment: in dplyr 1.0.0, `date_format()` is deprecated, and should be replaced by `label_date()`. If you don't want to load the scales library as in this example, just use the long form `scales::label_date()`